# my spring-boot mvc application always shutdown by showing

Tags: spring-boot

```
   .   ____          _            __ _ _
  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)


 2017-09-03 16:43:53.881  INFO 6584 --- [           main] c.n.SpringBootMvcExampleApplication      : Starting SpringBootMvcExampleApplication on lenovo-PC with PID 6584 (C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\SpringBootMVCExample\target\classes started by lenovo in C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\SpringBootMVCExample)
 2017-09-03 16:43:53.896  INFO 6584 --- [           main] c.n.SpringBootMvcExampleApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
 2017-09-03 16:43:54.218  INFO 6584 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6e38921c: startup date [Sun Sep 03 16:43:54 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
 2017-09-03 16:43:56.213  INFO 6584 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup 2017-09-03 16:43:56.294  INFO 6584 --- [           main] c.n.SpringBootMvcExampleApplication      : Started SpringBootMvcExampleApplication in 3.284 seconds (JVM running for 3.931)
 2017-09-03 16:43:56.297  INFO 6584 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6e38921c: startup date [Sun Sep 03 16:43:54 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
 2017-09-03 16:43:56.304  INFO 6584 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: please share your main method, are you using maven ? add "<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>"

Answer (score 3):

Please add the below dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Sometimes because of jar conflicts in maven, spring boot will shutdown automatically. So Please share `pom.xml` if the problem still persists eventhough adding above dependency.

Comment: Marking `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as `provided` is only necessary when building a war that will be deployed to an external container. It's not clear that that is the case here

Comment: Without application server, web application won't start as it needs servlet container to start the application. spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency will act as embedded tomcat server. So please include this and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I was facing and I found that i did't tell the Spring about the server to be used. By adding below maven dependency it worked for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Later I investigate and found that the pom.xml inside the above artifact (spring-boot-starter-data-rest) itself reference the below maven artifacts, which instruct Spring to add the embedded server and use it while running the app which currently own this pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Interestingly when you go further in the POM file of the artifact (spring-boot-starter-web), you will see that it references for other artifact for tomcat server. Below is the maven artifact you will find in the pom.xml (spring-boot-starter-web)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Note**: As my application was using Rest based Controllers so I need Rest with Json support.  So below maven dependency is suitable for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But those only want server integration, can use below dependency and it must work.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by removing the

> spring-boot-starter-tomcat

dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. This is caused by corrupted repositories. I could resolve this by removing apache repository in  `c:\users\myname\.m2\repository\org\apache`

Answer (score 0):

Deleting folder; `users\myname\.m2\repository\org\apache`, and updating maven dependencies of the project worked for me.

As earlier I was using apache tomcat explicitly and now I started learning Spring whose internal dependency also includes apache tomcat. Which causes conflict.